# For loop in MVC not working for different MapRoute

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to MVC but I am fairly good with C#. So I was fiddling with MVC in Visual Studio where I came across this problem and I'm unable locate the cause of this error.

I'm trying to print a variable n number of times. It works very well when i use the given URL

```
http://localhost:18665/HelloWorld/Welcome?namelala=Rob&numtimes=3
```

The output is as expected -

```
This is Rob
This is Rob
This is Rob
```

However when I try the same with this URL

```
http://localhost:18665/HelloWorld/Welcome/3/Rob
```

The output is

```
This is Rob
```

My RouteConfig code :

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }


            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Name_Route",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{numtimes}/{namelala}"

                );
        }
    }
}
```

HomeController Code

```
public ActionResult Welcome(string namelala, int numtimes=1)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "This is " + namelala;
            ViewBag.numtimes = numtimes;

            return View();
        }
```

Welcome.cshtml Code

```
<h2>Welcome here</h2>
<ul>
    @{
        for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.numtimes; i++)
        {
            <li>@ViewBag.Message</li>
        }

    }
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your routes are in the wrong order. The most specific route needs to be before the default.

Comment: So it means only one will work at one time ? Is there a way to make sure both way the loop works ?
EDIT :-------------
I moved my custom Route on top. Both are working fine now. Thanks :)

Comment: Routing evaluate each route and as soon as one matches, the given handler will be called (eg. Controller & Action). You can debug which route did match using Glimpse (http://getglimpse.com).

Answer (score 0):

Change your route config to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Name_Route",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{namelala}/{numtimes}"
);
```

To match your method signature:

```
public ActionResult Welcome(string namelala, int numtimes=1)
```

And also, in line with Stephen's comment, move the route about the default route